# Batch insert using jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate confusion

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, spring-jdbc

Does `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` execute multiple single insert statements **OR** 1 multi value list insert on the database server?

I know that it sends the complete query payload at once to the server but am not sure how the execution takes place.

Can someone please explain/help?

Comment: There are 5 different `batchUpdate` methods in [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html). They might do it 5 different ways, so which one are you asking about?

Comment: I was curious about 
```int[] org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs, int[] argTypes)```

Comment: You already know it sends the whole payload? What do you mean by that. Batching means, in the end, 1 INSERT statement with multiple values if the DB supports this!

Comment: @M.Deinum *Incorrect.* Batching means to send multiple requests to the database together. Usually, that means 1 statement, many sets of parameters for that statement, but you can also batch multiple statements, otherwise what would be the use of [`jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String... sql)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#batchUpdate-java.lang.String...-) and the underlying [`statement.addBatch(String sql)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#addBatch-java.lang.String-) that it calls?

Comment: That is the JDBC side, not the server side. How the JDBC driver implements this, is not necessarily how the DB server executes it. For MySQL for instance the driver expects single `INSERT INTO ... VALUES ()` statements, which get rewritten by the driver to 1 single `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(), VALUES()` statement.

Answer (score 3):

From question:

> Does `jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate` execute multiple single insert statements **OR** 1 multi value list insert on the database server?

From [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58922330/batch-insert-using-jdbctemplate-batchupdate-confusion?noredirect=1#comment104114442_58922330):

> I was curious about `int[] org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs, int[] argTypes)`

*TL;DR:* **It executes 1 multi-valued list.**

---

Spring Framework is open-source, so it's easy to look at the source code and see that is actually does.

[**`batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs, final int[] argTypes)`**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L984)

```
@Override
public int[] batchUpdate(String sql, List<Object[]> batchArgs, final int[] argTypes) throws DataAccessException {
    if (batchArgs.isEmpty()) {
        return new int[0];
    }

    return batchUpdate(
            sql,
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    Object[] values = batchArgs.get(i);
                    int colIndex = 0;
                    for (Object value : values) {
                        colIndex++;
                        if (value instanceof SqlParameterValue) {
                            SqlParameterValue paramValue = (SqlParameterValue) value;
                            StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(ps, colIndex, paramValue, paramValue.getValue());
                        }
                        else {
                            int colType;
                            if (argTypes.length < colIndex) {
                                colType = SqlTypeValue.TYPE_UNKNOWN;
                            }
                            else {
                                colType = argTypes[colIndex - 1];
                            }
                            StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(ps, colIndex, colType, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return batchArgs.size();
                }
            });
}
```

As can be seen, it calls the following method.

[**`batchUpdate(String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss)`**](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v5.2.1.RELEASE/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#L930)

```
@Override
public int[] batchUpdate(String sql, final BatchPreparedStatementSetter pss) throws DataAccessException {
    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Executing SQL batch update [" + sql + "]");
    }

    int[] result = execute(sql, (PreparedStatementCallback<int[]>) ps -> {
        try {
            int batchSize = pss.getBatchSize();
            InterruptibleBatchPreparedStatementSetter ipss =
                    (pss instanceof InterruptibleBatchPreparedStatementSetter ?
                    (InterruptibleBatchPreparedStatementSetter) pss : null);
            if (JdbcUtils.supportsBatchUpdates(ps.getConnection())) {
                for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
                    pss.setValues(ps, i);
                    if (ipss != null && ipss.isBatchExhausted(i)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    ps.addBatch();
                }
                return ps.executeBatch();
            }
            else {
                List<Integer> rowsAffected = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++) {
                    pss.setValues(ps, i);
                    if (ipss != null && ipss.isBatchExhausted(i)) {
                        break;
                    }
                    rowsAffected.add(ps.executeUpdate());
                }
                int[] rowsAffectedArray = new int[rowsAffected.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < rowsAffectedArray.length; i++) {
                    rowsAffectedArray[i] = rowsAffected.get(i);
                }
                return rowsAffectedArray;
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (pss instanceof ParameterDisposer) {
                ((ParameterDisposer) pss).cleanupParameters();
            }
        }
    });

    Assert.state(result != null, "No result array");
    return result;
}
```

As can be seen, it creates a single `PreparedStatement`, enters a loop calling `addBatch()`, and finally calls `executeBatch()`.

So, the short answer is: **1 multi-valued list**.

The full answer is that it *likely* sends one SQL statement and a multi-valued list to the database server, however it is entirely up to the JDBC driver how it actually implements batching, mostly limited by what the communication protocol supports, so the only way to know for sure is to *trace* the communication with the server.

Comment: After some testing I found varying results depending on the rewriteBatchedStatements = true property in the connection string.  

For same code got the following in sql general logs  

`with rewriteBatchedStatements = false  
SET autocommit=0  
insert into....  
insert into....  
insert into....  
commit  
  
with rewriteBatchedStatements = true  
SET autocommit=0  
insert into....values (),(),()  
commit`